# Resurrection of the dead. Only Jews?

Tags: gentiles, baal-teshuva, resurrection-of-the-dead, noahidism

One of the Maimonides' 13 principals is the belief in resurrection of the dead but what is the qualifier for this? Does this only include Jews? Does it only apply to  the righteous? Will Noachides rise again? Could evil Jews or evil gentiles that performed t'shuvah before death rise again? Sources?

Answer (score -4):

To answer your question fully we first have to define our terms.

**What is resurrection**

In his work called Chelek, Maimonides clearly indicates that the intellect (the nefesh) goes to the world to come and joins the higher intellect.[1] That is to say that there is no physical resurrection, only spiritual. The Shem Tov ben Yosef Shem Tom captures his thinking. He writes that he [Maimondies] “did not believe in a physical resurrection.” In the Mishneh Torah, he confirms this when he writes:

> “In the hereafter neither a body nor a body shape exists, but the souls of the righteous without bodies.”

Classical Judaism and Talmud(s) state that after the arrival of the messiah, a period will be followed by resurrection. However, many modern scholars now feel that this notion was brought into Judaism from pagan Zoroastrianism and Babylon. Like the names of the months which the rabbi honestly admit came from Babylonian gods. The closest hint to a bodily resurrection in the Bible can be found in Daniel 12 which is debatable. If we take the latter approach and say that resurrection is a spiritual endeavor then the only difference in the messianic age (olam haba) is that Jews will live in Israel and not be submerged under foreign rule nor will they be subject to enslavement by other nations. Although he does not deny a physical resurrection in his treatise, it has been noted by some scholars who doubt whether he ever wrote the Treatise on Resurrection, however, that too is debatable.

**Do only Jews go to heaven?**

Many traditional Jews feel that only Jews or only righteous Jews living in Israel will resurrect. The political message is obvious: come to Israel. It is also possible that the persecutions by non-Jews would prompt any rational Jew, understandably, to say that non-Jews have no share in the world to come and hence do not get resurrected at all. For example, the Spanish poet, Yehudah Halevi was convinced that Jews are biologically superior to non-Jews. Even Noahides or converts do not meet the criteria of a Jew. They are little better than animals.[2] Addionaonly, Adam, Abraham, Jacob were non-Jews who we'd expect would resurrect.

Contrary to this racist opinion was Maimonides who believed in universalism. Maimonides was proud to be an observant Jew. He was also proud of the Jewish people yet, he did not think Jews were superior and that this was innate, instilled into the Jewish people. He felt that Jews were no better than other people, save the obeisance of the Torah, respectfully. This being the only distinction of the Jew. But anyone could convert and indeed this would take place in the messianic age.[3]
Ruth was a gentile who converted and Kings David and Solomon, as well as the Messiah, will descend from her. We see from here that gentiles have the same capacity to become the greatest leaders as those who are born to Jewish parents.

In short, Everyone is created b’tzelem Elohim, “in the image of G-d." Maimonides defines this image to mean intelligence, hence it is a duty to use one's intellect because that is the closest thing to G-d and it is the thing that separates us from animals.

[1] Commentary to Mishnah, introduction to Perek Chelek and Mishneh Torah, Hilkhot Teshuvah 8.

[2] For support of this view see Rabbi Moshe Ben-Chaim's article in the Jewish Times "Jews: A super Race?".

[3] For more information please see Menachem Keller who stresses this point in his book Maimonides on Judaism and the Jewish people, and again in his article “Chosenness. Not Chauvinism: Maimonides on the Chosen People”

Comment: Please read the question again and check that you answer it. I don't quite see it

Comment: Again, a long and informative answer that simply undermines the very assumption of the Q. by providing one opinion - "*but Rambam thinks there'll be no resurrection.*" The Q. is based on the opinion of those (the majority) that do believe in it physically (Ramban?)

Comment: @AlBerko I have listed two opinions. (1) the Rambam who believed in a more spiritual resurrection and universalism (one which says even non-Jews are resurrected) and (2) the more traditional opinion of Yehudah Halevi, author of The Kuzari who felt that Jews are biologically superior to non-Jews.

Comment: @mbloch  I have listed two opinions. (1) the Rambam who believed in a more spiritual resurrection and universalism (one which says even non-Jews are resurrected) and (2) the more traditional opinion of Yehudah Halevi, author of The Kuzari who felt that Jews are biologically superior to non-Jews.

Comment: How is an eccentric and unsupported reinterpretation based off of medieval philosophy really relevant beyond a cursory mention for the sake of historical completeness?

Comment: @Yirmeyahu Good point. But the Rambam says that these are not only his views but the views of the prophets. Additionally, Maimonides felt that this "medieval philosophy" was lost and that he was the first in the span of 2,000 yrs to reinvent it, however, this does not give the same credence to the mystical book Zohar since that work was proven to be a forgery by Moses de León.

Comment: "Maimonides felt", so what?

Comment: His opinions do not matter to you?

Comment: Where did Maimonides ever suggest that we should accept his opinion because it was his rather than on the strength of his argument?  His arguments in this regard are clearly a product of his time.

Comment: I agree that we should not just accept anything. Many of his thinking was a product of his time, for example, he opinion about woman having fewer teeth. But be it as it may, we know his interpretations of the Bible are correct because it makes sense.

Comment: Then you would be able to defend his position using evidence and not his name...

Comment: Allow me to demonstrate why his position makes sense.

Comment: From a philosophical argument, it makes sense that the greatest pleasure a soul could endure would be to experience G-d. Why then, should the soul wish to rejoin the body in the world to come.

Comment: If you ask about universalism, it also makes sense that G-d loves all of His creations. The Bible says that people are created b’tzelem Elohim, “in the image of G-d." Genesis 2:7 reads: “The L-rd G-d formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a nefesh chayah.” Onkelos does not render this simply as “a living being,” but characterizes this as man's ruach m’mal’la, “one with the power of speech,” a phrase denoting a certain level of intelligence. Thus Maimonides is correct when he says that the image of G-d denotes intelligence.

Comment: @Yirmeyahu In short, the “image of God” (Tzelem Elohim) is, according to Maimonides, a faculty of reason. The intellect.